# How exactly does Arkhan the Black speak?

Tags: undead, warhammer-fantasy

In the *Warhammer Fantasy* universe, **how does Arkhan the Black speak?**

In the first *Neferta* novel he is described as if he's just a walking skeleton? No lips or tongue and probably no lungs or throat either so how does he get air into his mouth at all?

Does he communicate with telepathy or an undead speaker system hidden under his cloak maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arkhan the Black is a Liche in the Warhammer Fantasy universe. So he would talk how all other Liches are able to talk, which would be magic!

Comment: I was hoping for somthing a little more involved than 'It's Magic stupid'. But that's probably a perfectly reasonable answer.